# Highcharts synchronised chart with dropdown selection instead of legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts, filter, toggle

I'm looking for some help to connect the custom dropdowns to the chart legend for the below three synchronised charts.

Bascially, I would like to connect the 3 dropdowns to control the legends of each of the charts. Is this possible?

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5xch17m/2

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">


            <div class="col-lg-2">
         <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn  btn-block btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> --> Movement Direction</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Normal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Reverse</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">

      <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> --> Select Trends</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;RMS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Peak</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Direction</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">

      <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block  btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> --> Select Filters</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Location Temperature</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Minimum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Maximum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Threshold</a></li>
    </ul>


    </div>

    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve - similar to indicators: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/advanced-stock-chart/

Comment: What issue are you facing? I don't see a question. Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have clarified my question. I'm looking to sync the 3 charts to control their legends in dropdowns at the top of the page.

Comment: It is clearly possible as shown by your example. It takes some work to get there though. You have still not asked a [help/on-topic] question. What is the problem you are facing when trying to synchronize the dropdowns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `data-value` attribute of elements to the same as series names that they represent. Values like `option1` or `option2` mean little. Then it is much easier to link series with option in drilldown:

```
Highcharts.each(charts, function(chart) {
    Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(s) {
        if (s.name === val) {
            if (s.visible) {
                s.hide();
            } else {
                s.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1dk9x2tr/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#show